# Why is this macro contrasting Day_i with Day_(1-1) not working?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Why is this macro not working?

```
%MACRO Cerved_recap;

%let i=2;
%DO i = 2 %TO &oggi.;

%let ieri = %sysevalf(&i.-1);

data work.initial_db_cerved;
set work.initial_db_cerved;
length esito_&i. $ 10;
format esito_&i. $char20.;

%if ENCOURS_TOTAL_&i. < ENCOURS_TOTAL_&ieri. %then %do; esito_&i.='total_out';
%end;
%else %do; esito_&i.= '-';
%end;

run;

%end;
%MEND Cerved_recap;
%Cerved_recap;
```

Comment: What, specifically, is not working? Are you getting any errors? Is it giving you wrong numbers? What value does `&oggi` take? Can you post sample data that recreates the problem?

Comment: Your %IF statement makes no sense.  First the two strings you are comparing start with the exact same letters, so you are just testing if the macro variable I has a string that comes before the string in the macro variable IERI.  And you never defined that second macro variable anywhere.  Please explain in words what you are trying to do.  Show working SAS code that does not use any macro for a simple case like when &OGGI is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technical answer, to get a real answer explain in words what you are trying to do, and perhaps show an example of the working SAS code you are trying to use the macro to generate.

Since you set I to a digit string like 2 and set IERI to a digit string like 1 the test in your %IF statement will usually be false.  It is comparing a string like ENCOURS_TOTAL_2 to another string like ENCOURS_TOTAL_1 and since the beginning of those two strings are exactly the same it just like comparing the digit 2 to the digit 1.  The test will only be true when I has a value that is a power of 10 (10 100 1000 etc) because then you are comparing a string that starts with the digit 1 to a string that starts with the digit 9.

Perhaps you wanted to compare the values of SAS variables with those names?

If so then use actual SAS statements instead of macro statements.

```
if ENCOURS_TOTAL_&i. < ENCOURS_TOTAL_&ieri. then esito_&i.='total_out';
else esito_&i.= '-';
```

Comment: Yes, in fact it actually worked when (randomly, 'cause i'm a beginner and i didn't know what to try any more) i changed %if with if (%end with end, etc.). So, i think I understand the general meaning of your comment (thank you!), but then, which is the rule to follow in macros when deciding to write an if statement with or without %? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use an %IF statement when you want to use that MACRO statement to control how the macro decides what SAS code it should generate.  And use the the IF statement when you want the macro to generate that SAS statement as part of the SAS code that the macro is generating.  Avoid using macro code to generate SAS code until you know enough SAS code to understand what SAS code you would like the macro code to generate.